# Folder not accessible by users but accessible by web server

Tags: html, css, image, permissions, directory

I have a folder in my website, and I do not want users to be able to access the content within this folder.
However, I *do* want the web server to be able to access files within this folder, and display them to users.

For example, if pictures were stored inside the folder, if a user went to http://mydomain.com/pics/image.jpg I would not want them to be able to view the image. However, if there was another page in my website, which either used an  tag to reference the image, or the image was referenced in a css background, I would want the image to show up on the page.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Hotlink protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not if you want them to be visible through a plain HTML img tag or CSS background. 
The browser cannot display the image if the user has no rights to see it.

You could generate an image dynamically in the background perhaps to achieve the same result. But it will not work for css (at least I would not know how to..)

Why do you want to achieve this?

**Update:**
Now your question is clear;

When the file is uploaded, restrict access to uploaduser only
After that, move it to a public folder.

[Still this will not solve it for CSS background unless you somehow have the user edit the CSS file]

Comment: I have a PHP/MySQL login system, and was trying to add a feature to upload pictures and sounds. Until the user makes them public, I do not want the pictures/sounds to be visible by anyone else.

Comment: Restrict access and move to public folder upon user action ?